# TouchScreen Nokia C5 -J2ME's Command Action buttons and Scrolling do not work after changing system time

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, touchscreen

I am starting my app, and it is working well... but After...:

1. Going to "Settings-> Phone-> Date and time",change the time backward.(MyApp is onbackground)
2. Re-opening tested application
3. Trying to use left command action and rıght command actıon.... scrolling...

J2ME's Actıon Commands aren't working at all. Also touchscreen's scrolling is not working...!

... start executing the application is operating normally. So "im2amit" who is from forum.nokia, proposed to re-create my object. I use HideNotify()/showNotify() for sense app is background.. they work good, But if I change system time backward, showNotify Method doesn't work..?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you end the application after changing time and again start it ?

If yes, its the problem with the application going in background. I mean whenever your application goes in background, it actually looses some active objects from memory.

So instead of  changing time, try to do something else while your application is in background, I guess it will also yield the same results.